# Why is my SurfaceView so "jumpy" with its animations?

Tags: android, animation, rotation, surfaceview

I'm making a simple rotating animation of 2 images, one on top of another (each with a different speed). I know there is already an Animation API, but I need to use this one instead.

It works well, but from time to time, the animations stop for a very short time and then continue, making it "jumpy" (stays on some frames much more than on the others).

Why does it occur? because of GC? What can I do to avoid it? I intend to do some background operations, so it might get even slower.

I know that using sleep() doesn't really mean the thread will wake up right after the given time, but this is too much and it's very noticeable .

Are there any tricks to make it smoother? maybe use a better alternative?

Here's the code (of the view that does it) :

```
public class AnimView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
  {
  int                     _angle;
  private final Bitmap    _bitmap;
  private final Paint     _paint =new Paint();
  private AnimationThread _animationThread;
  private Matrix          _matrix;
  private int             _width;
  private int             _height;

  public AnimView(final Context context)
    {
    super(context);
    _bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    _paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

  public AnimView(final Context context,final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
    super(context,attrs);
    _bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    _paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

  public AnimView(final Context context,final AttributeSet attrs,final int defStyle)
    {
    super(context,attrs,defStyle);
    _bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    _paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

  @Override
  public void surfaceChanged(final SurfaceHolder holder,final int format,final int width,final int height)
    {
    _width=width;
    _height=height;
    }

  @Override
  public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
    if(isInEditMode())
      return;
    _matrix=new Matrix();
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    _animationThread=new AnimationThread();
    _animationThread.start();
    }

  @Override
  public void surfaceDestroyed(final SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
    _animationThread.cancelAnimation();
    }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas)
    {
    if(isInEditMode())
      {
      canvas.drawColor(0xffff0000);
      return;
      }
    _paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    _matrix.reset();
    _matrix.postScale(_width/_bitmap.getWidth(),_height/_bitmap.getHeight());
    _matrix.postRotate(_angle,_width/2,_height/2);
    canvas.drawBitmap(_bitmap,_matrix,_paint);
    _matrix.reset();
    _matrix.postScale(_width/_bitmap.getWidth(),_height/_bitmap.getHeight());
    _matrix.postRotate(_angle*2,_width/2,_height/2);
    canvas.drawBitmap(_bitmap,_matrix,_paint);
    }

  private class AnimationThread extends Thread
    {
    private boolean _isRunning =true;

    public AnimationThread()
      {}

    public void cancelAnimation()
      {
      _isRunning=false;
      }

    @Override
    public void run()
      {
      while(_isRunning)
        {
        postInvalidate();
        refreshDrawableState();
        try
          {
          sleep(5);
          }
        catch(final InterruptedException e)
          {
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
        _angle=(_angle+1)%360;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
@Override
public void run()
  {
    long last = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long currentTime = last;
    long frameTime = 40;
  while(_isRunning)
    {
      currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      if(currentTime - last > frameTime){
        postInvalidate();
        refreshDrawableState();
       //I FORGOT THIS
          last = currentTime;
      }
    try
      {
        sleep(5);  
      }
    catch(final InterruptedException e)
      {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
    _angle=(_angle+1)%360;
    }
  }
}
```

This way you refresh your screen every 40ms and update your position every 5ms. Also this is just one part, you can set your matrix update and calculations also out of the drawing part, and this will increase your speed too. The less calculations you do on actuall draw time the faster it will be.

EDIT: Take a look at this

```
public class AnimView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
int _angle;
private final Bitmap _bitmap;
private final Paint _paint = new Paint();
private AnimationThread _animationThread;
private Matrix _matrix;
private int _width = 100;
private int _height = 100;
private Bitmap backBitmap;
private Canvas backCanvas;

public AnimView(final Context context) {
    super(context);
    _bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    _paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);      
}

public AnimView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    _bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    _paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);      
}

public AnimView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
        final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    _bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    _paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(final SurfaceHolder holder, final int format,
        final int width, final int height) {
    _width = width;
    _height = height;
    createImage();
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (isInEditMode())
        return;
    _matrix = new Matrix();
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    _animationThread = new AnimationThread();
    _animationThread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(final SurfaceHolder holder) {
    _animationThread.cancelAnimation();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    if (isInEditMode() || backBitmap == null) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xffff0000);
        return;
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(backBitmap, 0, 0, _paint);
}

private class AnimationThread extends Thread {
    private boolean _isRunning = true;

    public AnimationThread() {
    }

    public void cancelAnimation() {
        _isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long last = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long currentTime = last;
        long frameTime = 40;
        long updateTime = 20;
                    boolean updated = false;
        while (_isRunning) {
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (currentTime - last > frameTime) {
                postInvalidate();
                refreshDrawableState();
                last = currentTime;
                                    updated = false;
            }
            else if(currentTime - last > updateTime){
                                if(!updated){
                drawImage();
                                    updated = true;
                                }
            }
            try {
                sleep(5);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            _angle = (_angle + 1) % 360;
        }
    }
}

private void createImage(){
    backBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(_width, _height, Config.ARGB_8888);
    backCanvas = new Canvas();
    backCanvas.setBitmap(backBitmap);
}

private void drawImage(){
    backCanvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);
    _paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    _matrix.reset();
    _matrix.postScale(_width / _bitmap.getWidth(),
            _height / _bitmap.getHeight());
    _matrix.postRotate(_angle, _width / 2, _height / 2);
    backCanvas.drawBitmap(_bitmap, _matrix, _paint);
    _matrix.reset();
    _matrix.postScale(_width / _bitmap.getWidth(),
            _height / _bitmap.getHeight());
    _matrix.postRotate(_angle * 2, _width / 2, _height / 2);
    backCanvas.drawBitmap(_bitmap, _matrix, _paint);
}
}
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your work

Comment: why would refreshing the screen be better than refreshing only the view? also, wouldn't putting too many variables (like the matrix ones) on different thraeds (the run() and the onDraw()) be problematic because of thread safety? i think that for this, i should use AtomicReference or double buffering or something.

Comment: maybe i should use a bitmap that will be used for the whole drawing, and draw on it, so that the onDraw will only have to draw it instead of doing calculations?

Comment: This was for you one method to replace and try, did you? :) Is it working for you or not?

Comment: it didn't fix it. sorry. from time to time, i get a frame that is shown more than the others.

Comment: I forgot last = currentTime, and take a look at second answer it contains double buffer.

Comment: it crashed with NPE because of the backCanvas so i've initialized it in the CTOR, and now it works, but from time to time it shows a black frame (or so it seems).

Comment: My mistake I was in a hurry, sorry for that. black screen is appearing because I left the drawImage to update all the time, not once, you take a look at edited run method now, this is just a hint, go with flag and update only once. You catch my point. Sorry once again I am in a rush so I made a mistake :)

Comment: still has the black frame issue. sorry.